# Java: Transferring JFrame focus to another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, window, focus, jframe

I have two separate applications, each running in its own JVM. App1 implements a ServerSocket and waits for requests. App2 implements a Socket and performs requests to App1.

App1 should become the active process / window after either App2 has performed a request (and transfers the focus to App1) or after App1 fulfilled the request (and grabs the focus).

How do I do that?

I tried to use the Window.toFront() method on App1, but all that happens is a blinking bar in the taskbar.

Comment: You may need to use JNI or JNA to solve this although the solution will then be platform dependent. Are you 100% sure that these applications need to run in separate JVM's?

Comment: Please don't include noise like sigs in questions.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. Both applications run independent. App1 is an application I wrote for my company while App2 is a third party software written by some of our partners. App1 will be replaced by App2 in the medium-term. So for now our agents will work with App2 and if needed lookup additional information in App1. To simplify the workflow the lookup can be issued from App2. So my superiors wanted a solution where a lookup can be issued from App2 (which works fine thanks to the socket pattern) and then transfer the focus from App2 to App1 to display the desired information.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [requestFocusInWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29) or [requestFocus()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus%28%29) in combination with toFront(). However, there is no guarantee that this will be successful. Focus behavior is platform-dependent to certain extend.

From another question this function seems to work on Windows 7:

```
private void BringToFront() {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(jFrame != null) {
                jFrame.toFront();
                jFrame.repaint();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer a bit but depending on the OS requesting focus of a component in a JFrame might make the window come on front. I know it works on Windows XP but never tried on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks. Downvote deleted, upvote given. It's worth an attempt to see if this will work.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. I tried all possible combinations on a Windows XP machine with no success. All tries just highlighted App1's bar in the taskbar.

Comment: I tried your code example above. I tried JFrame.requestFocus(), JFrame.requestFocusInWindow(), JFrame.repaint() and variations of the code example and the mentioned methods.